# Is it possible to modify flying brooms?

Tags: harry-potter, flying-brooms

Like in real life and the Fast & Furious, vehicles are modified with custom parts to customize various aspects of the vehicle like speed, acceleration, control, etc. Is it ever done with flying brooms in the wizarding world of Harry Potter?

In Harry Potter and The Philosopher's Stone, we see that Prof. Quirrell is trying to make the flying broom go crazy while Prof. Snape trying to counter it. Thus, it is possible to modify the flying broom.

Has this possibility utilized to enhance the performance of the flying broom?

Comment: Previously on Pimp my Ride

Comment: @Shevliaskovic - You may laugh, but see below.

Comment: Have you seen Moody's broom?

Comment: Moody's broom looks like it has more of cosmetic mods rather than performance based mods

Comment: it would be much nicer, if the brooms came with cup holder or can be fitted later on... :)

Comment: Imagine a broom equipped with laser cannons and rocket propelled chainsaws...

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Comment: I can only imagine a broom after a trip through Pep Boys...

Answer (score 13):

Seen in a "blink and you'll miss it" scene in Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince (in The Weasley's Joke Emporium) was the [Broom Broom Kit](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Broom_Broom_kit), promising to...

> ***Bling up your broom!***

...with a custom pointed nosecone, spoiler and rocket booster.

[image]

Additionally, [Alastor Moody's broom](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15331/was-mad-eye-moodys-recumbent-broom-a-help-or-hindrance-in-the-battle-of-the-sev) appears to have a number of after-market modificiations. That said, it's not immediately clear if these *enhance* the performance of the broom.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hermione gives Harry a kit to take care of his broom, and in the kit it comes with a few addons, like a compass and a few sliver "tailpipes" basically.

Comment: I get this strange feeling that the addons you can get from the weasley's shop would more of a prank-y tipe mod, instead of actually enhancing performance.

Comment: @LepelLeLama - The nosecone and spoiler certainly seem stupid.

Comment: Now I wonder what the "tank" on Moody's broom holds.  Sure, made to look like a Harley with a peanut tank, but...

Comment: @ZeissIkon - Almost certainly booze

Comment: LOL. A rocket booster is a great mod.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

In the movies, of course, there are a variety  of modifications, as detailed in the other answers. However, we also have some evidence from the books. Harry once received a broomstick servicing kit that contained a few interesting items:

> There was a large jar of Fleetwood's High-Finish Handle Polish, a pair
> of gleaming silver Tail-Twig Clippers, a tiny brass compass to clip on
> your broom for long journeys, and a Handbook of Do-It-Yourself
> Broomcare.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*

The clip-on compass clearly counts as an after-market modification, though it is not for performance.

On the other hand, although not something that one must physically attach to the broom, the Tail-Twig Clippers suggest that people trim their brooms, presumably for performance.